# Convert single LINQ value to string

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am pulling a single value from the db using LINQ:

```
    public string GetPoliceDepartmentName(int id)
    {
        var PoliceDepartmentName = from p in db.PoliceDepartmentList
                                   join l in db.TrespassOrder on p.PoliceDeptId equals l.PoliceDepartmentId
                                   where l.IncidentId == id
                                   select p.DepartmentName.Single();
        return PoliceDepartmentName.ToString();
    }
```

The method runs, but instead of returning the expected "Boston PD", it returns System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.Char]

I'm not sure why my method isn't converting from queriable to string.  I will keep researching, but a hint would be nice at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `Single` on `string`, which is `IEnumerable<char>`, so you'll get first (and only) char from string. That's probably not what you're looking for.

With proper brackets, you won't need `ToString` call at all, because `PoliceDepartmentName` will be types as `string` automatically.

```
var PoliceDepartmentName = (from p in db.PoliceDepartmentList
                           join l in db.TrespassOrder on p.PoliceDeptId equals l.PoliceDepartmentId
                           where l.IncidentId == id
                           select p.DepartmentName).Single();
return PoliceDepartmentName;
```

Comment: Ok working now.  I added brackets, changed .Single to .First and removed the .ToString.  I understand the single thing (char instead of whole string) causing a problem, but why did I need brackets? Oh, is it because without the brackets, I am calling .FIrst on just p.DepartmentName instead of the whole query?

Comment: Exactly. You're taking single char for each `DepartmentName`, instead of just single `DepartmentName` from entire collection.

Answer (score 3):

You need brackets :

```
(from p in db.PoliceDepartmentList
 join l in db.TrespassOrder on p.PoliceDeptId equals l.PoliceDepartmentId
 where l.IncidentId == id
 select p.DepartmentName).Single();
```